# python3 memoryview object to C function char* parameter

Tags: python, qt, ctypes, pyside2

The frame is following: PySide2 [QImage](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-5.15/PySide2/QtGui/QImage.html) gives me access to the internal pixel data with the `bits()` - call. The call returns memoryview - object that i would like to pass C-library function that does processing on the image pixel data (say it does super-fancy-blur for an example).

Problem is that i have not found a way to get memoryview underlaying data as ctypes call parameter.

That is: how can i get from memoryview object `ctypes.c_void_p` (or similar) -- without making copy of the buffer. The memoryview `tobytes()` returns bytes, but its copy from the memory, and so modifying that will not modify the original image (pixel data).

Now the minimal example python `silly.py` side is:

```
import ctypes
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage

img = QImage(500,100, QImage.Format.Format_RGB32 )
data = img.bits()
print(data)

dll = ctypes.CDLL( "./silly.o" )
dll_set_image = getattr( dll, "set_image" )
dll_set_image.argtypes = [ ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_uint32 ]
# Next line gives: ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
dll_set_image( data, img.width(), img.height() )
```

C-"dll": `silly.c`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void set_image( void* data, uint32_t xsize, uint32_t ysize )
{
   printf("Data set %lx %d %d", (uint64_t)data, xsize, ysize );
}
```

Compiling and testing:

```
% gcc -shared -o silly.o silly.c
% python3 silly.py              
<memory at 0x7f2f9806a700>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "silly.py", line 13, in <module>
    dll_set_image( data, img.width(), img.height() ) 
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: QImage::bits() returns (const) unsigned char* and not void*

Comment: This is true, but it does not affect the issue in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `memoryview` supports the Python buffer protocol, so create a `ctypes` array of the appropriate size using its `from_buffer` method, which won't make a copy but reference the same memory.

Modifying your example slightly to see the buffer change:

silly.c:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API void set_image(unsigned char* data, uint32_t xsize, uint32_t ysize)
{
    printf("%p %u %u\n",data,xsize,ysize);
    *data = 123;
}
```

test.py:

```py
import ctypes
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage

img = QImage(500,100, QImage.Format.Format_RGB32 )
data = img.bits()
print('original:',data[0])

dll = ctypes.CDLL('./silly')
dll_set_image = dll.set_image
dll_set_image.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_uint32

buffer = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(data)).from_buffer(data)
dll_set_image(buffer, img.width(), img.height())
print('final:',data[0])
```

Output:

```
original: 80
00000213CCF3C080 500 100
final: 123
```

Comment: how to convert "unsigned char *" to python bytes by use pybind11?

Answer (score 0):

[`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) is not a void * but a structure ([`Py_buffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.Py_buffer)) that within its members is the buffer, so the conversion is not direct.

In these cases I prefer to use Cython(`python -m pip install cython`) that allows creating wrappers to libraries in a simple way. Considering the above I have created a project:

```
├── main.py
├── psilly.c
├── psilly.pyx
├── setup.py
├── silly.c
├── silly.h
└── silly.pxd
```

**silly.h**

```
extern void set_image( unsigned char* data, uint32_t xsize, uint32_t ysize, uint32_t channels);
```

**silly.c**

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#include "silly.h"

void set_image( unsigned char* data, uint32_t xsize, uint32_t ysize, uint32_t channels)
{
    // fill white color
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < (xsize * ysize * channels); i++)
    {
        data[i] = 255;
    }
}
```

**silly.pxd**

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t

cdef extern from "silly.h":  
    void set_image(unsigned char* data, uint32_t xsize, uint32_t ysize, uint32_t channels)
```

**psilly.pyx**

```
cimport silly

cpdef set_image(unsigned char[:] data, int width, int height, int channels):
    silly.set_image(&data[0], width, height, channels)
```

**setup.py**

```py
from distutils.core import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension(
    name="psilly",
    sources=["psilly.pyx", "silly.c"],
)
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

**main.py**

```py
import psilly

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QWidget
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap

app = QApplication()

img = QImage(500, 100, QImage.Format.Format_RGB32)
data = img.bits()

label1 = QLabel()
label1.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img.copy()))

psilly.set_image(data, img.width(), img.height(), 4)

label2 = QLabel()
label2.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))

widget = QWidget()
lay = QHBoxLayout(widget)
lay.addWidget(label1)
lay.addWidget(label2)
widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

Compiling and testing:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python main.py
```

Output:

[image]

Note: When the project is compiled, it is generated as an intermediate element to psilly.c where you will see the conversion between memoryview and `unsigned char *` using the Py_buffer structure.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake ppl finding this page from google, yet another alternative that works is based on making python module with C/C++ as described on [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html).

It requires some boilerplate, but the actual access to buffer is easy:

```
PyObject* set_image(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) 
{
    Py_buffer buffer;
    long xsize;
    long ysize;
    int ok = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y*ll", &buffer, &xsize, &ysize); 

    if ( ok != 1 )
        return NULL;

    printf("Data set: %d %d - %lx\n", (int)xsize, (int)ysize, (unsigned long)buffer.buf );

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```